# Difference between total_due & base_total_due

Tags: magento2, orders, payment

When I get order data I can see there is total_due and base_total_due. My question is what is the difference between these?

Basically I get to see if the order has been paid fully and unsure which I should check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On order tables, you can see **lot of columns name start** with `base_` .

`base_` save price in **base currency** and  `non base_` save current **currency  price value**.

It created for  **bcoz** of Multi currencies.

Suppose, you have a store which has multi-currency USD, Euro

> And **`USD is used base currency at Magento`** and `Euro is another
>   currency` at Magento.So when you *have placed an order 100Euro from the
>   store* which current currency is euro then Magento  `save 121 USD` In
>   `base_.*` column and   `*. column` save 100.And Magento admin, you
>   have set  Euro to USD conversion rate is **1.21**.